# Get information about file

Tags: c#, file, class-library

I want to create class library project to use it in my projects but for now i don't know what is the best option to solve my problem. 
I want to pass File that will chosen by `OpenFileDialog` after that i want to pass selected file to my class function to get data about it ( Name, MimeType, Content of file & convert it to base64)

I don't have issue with base64 conversion or with create class lib or deploy it but my issue is what is the best option to pass this file to my function and work with it, I have options like pass file path or pass `File` Object or pass `FileStream` but how to get my required data (Name, MimeType, Content) from each option, I search for it and find many options when send file path but can anyone tell me this is good idea to work with or there is any better idea ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);

Now you can use, fi.Name, fi.Length, fi.Exists, etc.

replace the file path with fi

Example:
File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

replace "test.txt" with fi.tostring();

and how to read is upto you

Comment: As its name suggest it's only for obtaining information about the file and not the actual file content, what I would recommend is pass the file path in the method and perform file operations in that method (with the use of FileInfo and File objects).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by passing the full path of the file to the function